# Form.Owner set from separate thread in .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, .net-3.5

I am writing a test application where I need to put Form on separate thread.

So if I create Form window from main thread and set its .Owner = this everything works.
If I spawn thread UIThread and set Owner from new thread I get exception.
Getting exception is understandable since you can't access forms directly.
My question is is there a message that I need to catch on main thread and do BeginInvoke to push it on it's message pump? Since UIForm ShowInTaskbar is set to false I need to click on main application in taskbar and restore with all its children windows.

```
private void UIThread() // New Thread call
{
        UIForm form = new UIForm();

        form.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        form.Owner = this;

        Application.Run(form); // Expected Exception
}
```

Comment: You'll have to pinvoke SetParent to get around this.  Best thing to do is to not do this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, maybe Application.Run shall be called only once per application. See if this one will work for you

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
-----------------
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var thread = new Thread(
            () =>
                {
                    var form2 = new Form {Owner = this};
                });
        thread.Start();
    }
}
```